# Android Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT - Sort by last modified time

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a File Picker in my Android project where the files would be by default:

- from the download directory
- sorted by the last modified date

I have managed to create the intent but the files are sorted alphabetically.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
Uri uriDownload = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,uriDownload);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_SHARED_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Can anybody help? thanks

Comment: In the picker gui the user can choose the sort modes.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, but I would like to set the appropriate ranking for my use case which is to sort by most recent modified files first.